# "Торпедо" и "торпеда": в чем разница?

Tags: значение-слов

Какая разница в значениях слов "торпедо" и "торпеда"?

Answer (score 4):

Это одно и то же.
Торпеда- 1. рыба из семей скатов, обладающая способностью при нападении и защите производить электрические удары.. Латинское название этого ската – «torpedo», происходит от слова «окоченеть», «оцепенеть», которое описывает эффект, возникающий в руке от электрического удара.

2.самодвижущийся подводный снаряд - от фр. «la torpille».

Торпедо - автомобильный стиль и название спортивного клуба автомобилистов. Называется так, потому что передаёт стремительность торпеды-снаряда и вызывает ошеломление.В начале 19 века у французского слова «la torpille» было еще одно значение, восходящее к этому же латинскому корню: ошеломление, произведенное чем-либо или кем-либо. Можно даже сказать, «обалдение». Например, прозвище Эстер, героини романа О. де Бальзака «Блеск и нищета куртизанок», было «Торпиль», то есть «электрический скат»(как электрошокер). Одним из первых автомобилей в ошеломительном стиле «la torpille» считается 45-сильный «Мерседес» производства 1908 года,при экспорте  автомобилей этого стиля (мерседесов)в Англию возникла проблема с переводом. Не слишком разбирающиеся в тонкостях английского языка торговые агенты-франкофоны перевели французское «la torpille» на английский весьма приблизительно: не «stunning», а «torpedo». Автомобили типа «торпедо» были очень популярны в начале ХХ века вплоть до 1930-х годов

Название "Торпедо" для клуба предложил известный конькобежец Мельников: марка стремительного спортивного автомобиля подходит для названия спортивного клуба автомобилистов.  http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-36282/

Answer (score 3):

Суть в том, что оба слова действительно обозначают одно и тоже. Все значения (кроме типа кузова) происходят от латинского "torped**o**" (оцепенение), попавшего в русский язык путём прямого или косвенного (с английского) заимствования. Естественно, почти во всех случаях первым вариантом слова было через "о". Однако, безударная "о" на конце слова не прижилась и заменилась на "а". В этом легко убедится, если просмотреть историю слова "торпедо" по разным словарях.

В словарях иностранных слов Михельсона (1865), Чудинова (1910) и Павленкова (1907) слова торпед**а**, вы не обнаружите, а вот слово "торпедо" [есть](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/36328). В Энциклопедии Брокгауза и Ефрона (1907-1909), [тоже самое](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%20%D0%B8%20%D0%95%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE/)

У Ушакова (1935-40 гг) слову "торпед**о**" уже выделяют только значение *автомобиль сигарообразной формы с открытым кузовом* (ссылки: [1](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1056090), [2](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1056066)), и то наравне с написанием через "а".

Современные толковые словари "торпед**о**" не дают вовсе. Хотя данный вариант слова от этого не исчез. Например, "[Словарь автолюбителя от а до я](http://abvgd-auto.narod.ru/Buka/T.htm)" пишет:

> **торпеда** -
> передняя панель приборов в салоне автомашины
> **торпедо** - тип кузова - кабриолет без крыши и боковых стекол.

Встречаются и [другие](http://info.auto.ru/word/faq/article/5325.html) варианты:

> ТОРПЕДО - приборная доска автомобиля
> ТОРПЕДО-БОДИ - (англ. torpedo-body), сигарообразный кузов, кузов «торпедо»

Также на просторах интернета, мне не встретилось обозначение электрического ската как "торпеда", в то время как "торпедо", его хоть и не часто, но называют. Клуб же "Торпедо", своё название, получил в те времена, когда вариант через "о" был более предпочтительным для употребления.

Comment: О чем вообще разговор? 
Какой вариант был предпочтительнее? Для чего?
Вы тоже не видите разницу между маркой автомодиля и конструктивной схемой?
Я могу Вам объяснить. "Торпедом" (через О) называлая схема при которой на желехный лист крепился кузов и шасси. "Торпедой" (через А - приборная панель, название иногда употребляется до сиз пор). Маркой "Торпедо" могло быть только в составе собственного имени. "Газ-Торпедо" например. Правда это 50-е годы.      

Только это (как и остальное) не по теме, простите.

Comment: "Был **предпочтительней** для употребления" в значении тип кузова в официальной и литературной речи в 1930 году вариант "торпедо", хотя написание через "а", тоже было допустимо.

 Про какую марку автомобиля вы говорите, я не знаю, у меня в ответе такого словосочетания нет и не было.  

Для справки, далеко не все явления языка подаются чёткой детерминации, и вариативность в написании и/или произношении какого-либо слова явление  далеко не редкое.

Второй минус вашему ответу поставил я. За хамство и неадекватность действий.

Comment: >Был предпочтительней для употребления" в значении тип кузова в официальной и литературной речи в 1930 году вариант "торпедо", хотя написание через "а", тоже было допустимо.  
  
Это Ваш текст или вы ссылку забыли? Довольно странно вместо ответа на полемическое замечание повторять собственное высказывание и представляет его как истину.  
Давайте сначала. Я утверждаю, что Вы ошиблись или нечтко сформулировали  вот в этой фразе:   
>>"Торпедо", своё название, получил в те времена, когда вариант через "о" был более предпочтительным для употребления.    
  
Вариант для чего?

Comment: >Второй минус вашему ответу поставил я. За хамство и неадекватность действий.  

Взаимно. См. мой профиль.
Впрочем, я обычно не ставлю минусов по личным мотивам. Надо все-таки быть выше этого и понимать, что большинству читающих (если не всем) это совершенно неинтересно.

Comment: >Вариант для чего?

Вариант написания. В дореволюционных изданиях почти везде через "о", следовательно до появления советских словарей, зафиксировавших изменения, предпочтительней был вариант через "о". Все ссылки даны в самом ответе и дублировать их не вижу необходимости. Комментировать дальше не имеет смысла, потому и не буду.

Comment: >>Вариант написания.  

**Написания** чего? Вы путаетесь со **значением** слова, а написание было разным для разных значений. 

ЗЫ Есть предложение после объявления оппонента хамом и неадекватом не хлопать так демонстративно дверью. Тем более, что Вы это делаете не в первый раз, но каждый раз продолжаете "дискуссию". Личное мнение.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, можно ли считать это это "одним и тем же", но название "торпедо" вне спортивного контекста не употребляется. Во всяком случае, про марку(?) автомобиля я услышал впервые, всегда считал, что название "торпеда" применяется к гоночным автомобилям выпущенным до (примерно) 60-х годов из-за их сигарообразной формы. Но именно **торпеда**. Сейчас в силу ряда причин это название устарело, да и форма самих автомобилей изменилась. Сейчас в аналогичных целях чаще используется "болид".

Так что считаю "Торпедо" только именем собственным, применимым к спортивным командам. Кстати, тут не лишне будет вспомнить, что термины "команда" (спортивная), "клуб" (юридическое лицо) и устаревшее "спортивное общество" - это разные веши. Так, команды "Торпедо" принадлежали обществу "Труд". А "клуб" в подобных контекстах вообще не употреблялся во времена образования футбольной команды.

Кстати, маленькая деталь. На эмблеме клуба гонщик сидит как бы "задом наперед". 
[image]

На самом деле "толстая" часть такого автомобиля - перёд.

[image: "Альфа-Ромео" середины 30-х]. Типичная "торпеда".
"Альфа-Ромео" середины 30-х

Не знаю причину такой ошибки, видимо за образец была взята какая-то совсем нетипичная модель.

Comment: Позвольте с Вами не согласиться. "Торпедо"- именно клуб: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BЕ Кроме того:Торпедо/торпеда —1. приборная доска автомобиля.
 2. центральная консоль между передними сидениями, которая может перейти в подлокотник между передними сиденьями.
 3. автомобиль сигарообразной формы с открытым кузовом.
4.Торпедо — подводный или подземный взрывчатый снаряд.
5.— рыба рода скатов.
6.-полевые — искусственное препятствие, служат для усиления обороны укреплений, употребляются в полевой и крепостной войне.

Comment: http://zatorpedo.narod.ru/history.html     ИСТОРИЧЕСКАЯ СПРАВКА "ТОРПЕДО"
. Основана в 1924 г. как рабочий спортивный клуб «Рабочий Дворец «Пролетарская Кузница». Наименование «Торпедо» команда приняла в 1936 г, когда появилось одноимённое общество.  
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%EE%F0%EF%E5%E4%EE_(%F4%F3%F2%E1%EE%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9_%EA%EB%F3%E1,_%CC%EE%F1%EA%E2%E0)

Comment: Людмила, а с чем именно Вы не согласны?
Во-первых, первая Ваща ссылка битая, 
Во-вторых, в СССР 30-х годов ни о каких клубах в современном понимании просто и речи идти не могло. 
Посмотрите на всю страницу. Кто основан "как клуб"? Футбольная команда **"Торпедо" Москва**. 
То, что раньше могли назвать "клубом" никак не соответвует современному пониманию. 
ЗЫ Я с той станицы брал эмблему, так что ссылки эти для меня не новость.
Насчет автомобиля. Конструктивная схема - это никак не **марка**. Все остальное можно обсуждать, но это больше из истории автоспорта.

Comment: Что касается остальных значений, то я не могу запретить им сущствовать. Они очень специфические, я честно говоря сомневаюсь, что они есть в обычных словарях.

Comment: Ссылку повторяю, у меня работала:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE
В исторической справке говорится, что сначала был рабочий спортивный клуб «Рабочий Дворец «Пролетарская Кузница». Потом название стало "Торпедо", т.е. это всё-таки рабочий спортивный клуб "Торпедо",это же название и у команды. Не вижу ошибки.

Comment: Как видите, внизу перечислены все КЛУБЫ с таким названием

Comment: И что это доказывает? 
Ни один из них не был клубом в момент создания при Советской власти
Я Вас не обижу, если скажу, что Вы-то должны помнить советские коды.
Короче, о терминах я с Вами спорить  не буду. А по сути ответил. "Торпедо" в момент создлания не был клубом в современном понимании, т.е. юридически независимым лицом. Команды принадлежали **спортивным обществам**, а не клубам. В этом смысле ни одна команда не была клубом, хотя некоторые выступали под названием спортивных обществ ("Динамо", "Авангард" и др.). Это то существенное, что я хотел подчеркнуть.  
Давайте уже о языке.

Comment: Господа @Людмила и @behemothus, а что, популярных переводных романов-детективов не читали? Ведь слово "торпеда" давным давно укоренилось в русском для обозначения штатных мафиозных убийц или охранников.Никто даже не упомянул. Спорите о всяких несущественных деталях...